# wso2 api manager wso2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Tables are created but the data is not populated . followed the below steps https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics this link is used to configure

below is the error i see in the wso2carbon.log on wso2 api manager

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-16 20:15:50,544] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-16 20:15:59,210] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-10-16 20:16:01,473] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
```

Comment: </APIGateway> <EnableBillingAndUsage>false</EnableBillingAndUsage> <APIUsageTracking> <Enabled>true</Enabled> <PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeData‌​Publisher</PublisherClass> <ThriftPort>7614</ThriftPort> <BAMServerURL>tcp://hpgst010.jenie.ao.dcn:7614/</BAMServerURL> <BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername> <BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword> <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName> </APIUsageTracking>

Comment: above change is on wso2api . below iam posting wso2bam changes

Comment: Cluster> <Name>ClusterOne</Name> <!-- Node list of Cassandra cluster should be specified as a comma separated list eg. <Nodes>192.168.0.2:9160,192.168.0.3:9160,192.168.0.4:9160</Nodes> --> <Nodes>localhost:9163</Nodes>

Comment: -> <Offset>3</Offset> <!-- The JMX Ports --> <JMX>

Comment: how to make sure api is being used . even if there is no activity on API . it should some basic information in stats_db

Comment: right ..? any direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient} -  Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same. {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient i see this warning on wso2bam side

Answer (score 0):

No stats will be published if there is no activity on the API.  Please:
1. create API activity
2. wait 10 minutes for the bam analysis scripts to run
3. try to access the stats through API Manager again